# Lua gmatch odd characters (Slovak alphabet)

Tags: string, unicode, lua, coronasdk, lua-patterns

I am trying to extract the characters from a string of a word in Slovak. For example, the word for "TURTLE" is "KORYTNAČKA". However, it skips over the "Č" character when I try to extract it from the string:

```
local str = "KORYTNAČKA"
for c in str:gmatch("%a") do print(c) end
--result: K,O,R,Y,T,N,A,K,A
```

I am reading [this page](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1) and I have also tried just pasting in the string itself as a set, but it comes up with something weird:

```
local str = "KORYTNAČKA"
for c in str:gmatch("["..str.."]") do print(c) end
--result: K,O,R,Y,T,N,A,Ä,Œ,K,A
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Use texts encoded with 1-byte Slovak codepage instead of UTF-8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lua is 8-bit clean, which means Lua strings assume every character is one byte. The pattern `"%a"` matches one-byte character, so the result is not what you expected.

The pattern `"["..str.."]"` works because, a Unicode character may contain more than one byte, in this pattern, it uses these bytes in a set, so that it could match the character.

---

If UTF-8 is used, you can use the pattern `"[\0-\x7F\xC2-\xF4][\x80-\xBF]*"` to match a single UTF-8 byte sequence in Lua 5.2, like this:

```
local str = "KORYTNAČKA"
for c in str:gmatch("[\0-\x7F\xC2-\xF4][\x80-\xBF]*") do 
    print(c) 
end
```

In Lua 5.1(which is the version Corona SDK is using), use this:

```
local str = "KORYTNAČKA"
for c in str:gmatch("[%z\1-\127\194-\244][\128-\191]*") do 
    print(c) 
end
```

For details about this pattern, see [Equivalent pattern to “[\0-\x7F\xC2-\xF4][\x80-\xBF]*” in Lua 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22956136/1009479).

Comment: Adding a note here: the upcoming Lua 5.3 will add a basic `utf8` library.

Comment: When I try this, it gives me error: "malformed pattern (missing ']')". I am programming in Lua using Corona SDK.

Comment: @ArdentKid You got me, I think it's because Corona SDK is using Lua 5.1, but I haven't got it working yet. I asked [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22956136/1009479) about this, and will update this answer once somebody answers mine.

Comment: It looks like he's found a solution, however it's not really doing what I would like (parsing the individual characters) and doesn't include the odd character.

Comment: @ArdentKid See the update, `"[%z\1-\127\194-\244][\128-\191]*"` should work in Lua 5.1

Answer (score 1):

Lua has no built-in treatment for Unicode strings. You can see that `Ä,Œ` is a 2 bytes representing UTF-8 encoding of a `Č` character.

Yu Hao already provided sample solution, but for more details here is [good source](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaUnicode).

I've tested and found [this solution](http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/utf8) working properly in Lua 5.1, [reserve link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=5DFD60AE174578C6!278&authkey=!AHCzovnG80Cu2eE&ithint=file,.zip). You could extract individual characters using `utf8sub` function, see [sample](http://ideone.com/EjWLMo).

Answer (score 0):

```
string.gmatch(str, "[%z\1-\127\192-\253][\128-\191]*")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [utf8](https://docs.coronalabs.com/plugin/utf8/index.html) plugin. Then replace `string.gmatch` with `utf8.gmatch`.

Example (tested on Win7, it works for me)

```
yourfilename.lua

local utf8 = require( "plugin.utf8" )

for c in utf8.gmatch( "KORYTNAČKA", "%a" ) do print(c) end
```

and

```
build.settings

settings =
{
    plugins =
    {
        ["plugin.utf8"] =
        {
            publisherId = "com.coronalabs"
        },
    },      
}
```

Read more :

- [Introducing the UTF-8 string plugin](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2016/03/21/introducing-the-utf-8-string-plugin/),
- [Documenatation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/plugin/utf8/index.html) for utf8 plugin,
- [Lua String Manipulation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/data/luaString/index.html),
- [string.gmatch()](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/string/gmatch.html).

Have a nice day:)