# Equivalent pattern to "[\0-\x7F\xC2-\xF4][\x80-\xBF]*" in Lua 5.1

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

When [answering this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22954220/1009479), I wrote this code to iterate over the UTF-8 byte sequence in a string:

```
local str = "KORYTNAČKA"
for c in str:gmatch("[\0-\x7F\xC2-\xF4][\x80-\xBF]*") do 
    print(c) 
end
```

It works in Lua 5.2, but in Lua 5.1, it reports an error:

> malformed pattern (missing ']')

I recall in Lua 5.1, the string literal `\xhh` is not supported, so I modified it to:

```
local str = "KORYTNAČKA"
for c in str:gmatch("[\0-\127\194-\244][\128-\191]*") do 
    print(c) 
end
```

But the error stays the same, how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [Lua 5.1 manual on patterns.](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1)

```
A pattern cannot contain embedded zeros. Use %z instead.
```

In Lua 5.2, this was changed so that you could use `\0` instead, but not so for 5.1. Simply add `%z` to the first set and change the first range to `\1-\127`.

Comment: Simply replacing is not enough, `"[%z\1-\127\194-\244][\128-\191]*"` works, using `"%z"` as an individual character in the set.

Answer (score 3):

I highly suspect, this happens because of `\0` in the pattern. Basically, string that holds your pattern null-terminates before it should and, in fact, what lua regex engine is parsing is: `[\0`. That's clearly wrong pattern and should trigger the error you're currently getting.

To prove this concept I made little change to pattern:

```
local str = "KORYTNAČKA"
for c in str:gmatch("[\x0-\x7F\xC2-\xF4][\x80-\xBF]*") do 
    print(c) 
end
```

That compiled and ran as expected on lua 5.1.4. [Demonstration](http://ideone.com/kO3ByB)

**Note:** I have not actually looked what pattern was doing. Just removed `\0` by adding `x`. So output of modified code might not be what you expect.

**Edit:** As a workaround you might consider replacing `\0` with `\\0` (to escape null-termination) in your second code example:

```
local str = "KORYTNAČKA"
for c in str:gmatch("[\\0-\127\194-\244][\128-\191]*") do 
    print(c) 
end
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/ixLsav)

Comment: Yeah, I was going to say that it compiles in Lua 5.1, but the result is different. And I didn't find the support of `\xhh` in [Lua 5.1 reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html).

Comment: @YuHao What's the output in 5.2? I don't have lua installed.

Comment: The pattern should match a UTF-8 character, you can test it on [Lua demo](http://www.lua.org/demo.html)

Comment: @YuHao Updated answer. I don't really like it but this is the only workaround I can see here.